# Trigger a method by using beforeunload without popup dialog?

Tags: angular, typescript, onbeforeunload

**Without Dialog** ,I need to trigger a function with some backend code ,when the user closes the application.

Refer the code:

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onWindowClose(e: any): void {
    this.sessionObject.End = new Date();
    this.authService.updateUserSesson(this.sessionObject)
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';// here tried undefined and string type value
  }
```

Comment: Why not use ngOnDestroy on your outermost component? (Honest question. There might be an obvious answer why this wouldn't work )

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the easiest way to solve this is by making the function `async`. The code will be executed but there will be no confirmation dialog:

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
 async onWindowClose(e: any): void {
     ...
 }
```